# True & False is giving True in Python. Why?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, ampersand

I was doing a HandON with below Code:

```
for i in range(10,16):
    if(i%5==0 & i%3==0):
        print(i, 'both')
    elif i%5==0:
        print(i,'divisible by 5')
    elif i%3==0:
        print(i,'divisible by 3')
```

When I am executing this Code, it is giving Output as :

```
10 both
12 divisible by 3
15 both
```

Why is it giving 10 as divisible by both?
If it is  Bit-wise operator, then 'if' will have '0001' and '0000' for value 10, which should result in '0000'.
If I use 'and' instead of '&', it is giving correct answer.

Comment: `if((i%5==0) & (i%3==0))`

Comment: `True & False` is not `True` in python. (But then, what's going on here you ask?! Clearly, you're making an assumption that doesn't hold true. in this case, it's operator precedence. try brackets around the conditions before using `&`)

Comment: it evaluates the condition like this: `if i%5== (0 & (i%3==0)):`

Comment: @trotta Not a duplicate. OP is aware that & is bit-wise

Comment: The title of this question is under a wrong assumption; `python -c "print(True&False)"` apparently prints `False`.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Thanks for the detailed explanation.